# Need algorithm for optimization issue of distribution points among the set of attractor points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, distribution, computational-geometry, mathematical-optimization

We have the following optimization problem.

There are k (typically, k = 3-10) points on the plane, called attractors: A1, .., Ak.
And there is the set of points of size N (N is big, usually 10K-100K+) on the same plane.

We need to tie N1 points to the 1st attractor, N2 - to the 2nd, ..., Nk to the k-th. 
All points should be tied: N1 + ... + Nk = N.

The target function is like "points are tied to the nearest attractor and attractor has tied nearest points to itself":

> Let `Pij` be `j`-th point tied to `i`-th attractor `(i=1..k; j=1..Nk)`.
>
> Let `Lk` be sum of distances from `k`-th attractor to points that are tied to it:
>
> ```
> Lk = dist(Pk1, A1) + dist(Pk2, A2) + ... + dist(PkN1, A1).
> ```
>
> Let `f` be total sum of distances: `f = L1 + .. + Lk`.
>
> We need to minimize `f`.

Can someone provide some advice on how to implement that?
Or maybe there exist some known algorithm to do that?

**UPD:** This problem may be reduced to [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and solved by [hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). And it's special case of [minimum cost flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cost_flow_problem) problem.

Comment: @NiklasB. I removed the comment

Comment: So each attractor has a capacity and you want to assign the points so that the total sum of distances is minimized and no attractor is assigned more points than its capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear program that can be solved by general LP solvers.

It can also be modelled more specifically as a [min-cost max-flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) problem: Put the attractors on the left side of a bipartite graph and the points on the right side.

- Connect every attractor i on the left side to the source via an edge of capacity N_i and cost 0.
- Connect every point i on right side to the sink via an edge of capacity 1 and cost 0.
- Add edges from every attractor to every point with capacity 1 and the cost being their distance.

The minimum-cost max-flow in this graph is the solution to your problem. You can solve this for example using the method of [successive shortest paths](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=minimumCostFlow2) with Dijkstra.

Unfortunately I don't know theoretical bounds of this approach for the very specific properties of the graph (bipartite and total capacity n on the left side). I think the worst case for successive shortest paths is (polylog)quadratic, but in practice it should be much faster. Maybe somebody with more experience with linear programming and network optimization can say more about what the best algorithm would be to solve the arising cost-flow problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me promote LP on SO :). Some of the methods that you linked to are based on local search, which means that, if the initial solution is pretty good, then the number of (expensive) iterations is low. The greedy solution might work; one also could run something like Plotkin--Shmoys--Tardos at low accuracy. Another approach would be to exploit the symmetry of the problem in the unweighted subproblems arising in primal-dual. Probably it's worth poking the Scientific Computing SE or the non-SE OR-Exchange.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat In that case it might be worth starting out with a greedy next-fit nearest-neighbor-based solution. Unfortunately I have little knowledge of the theory behind this, so I can only make guesses about efficiency (let alone worst-case bounds)

Comment: Stable marriage is another possibility. I've done practical LP stuff, but pretty much always in branch-and-bound contexts where working on the branching strategy was the smart play.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I discovered that my problem may be reduced to [assignment problem]|(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and solved by [hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). And it's special case of min-cost-flow problem.

Comment: @VitalyTrifanov Wouldn't O(n^3) be much too slow for your scenario? That is the reason I didn't suggest Hungerian. The cost-flow problem can be solved at least in O(n^2 log n) using Dijkstra